# Buffer button changing forms

Tags: c#, click, mouse, buffer, wfp

this is my first post. I have a huge problem which make me headaches. I have an app uses WinForms, a TTS (Text-To-Speech) voice and custom-buttons with states.

In my 1st form -main- when I click a button, the app opens a 2nd form above the 1st. Ok.
When I close the 2nd form trough a button, I tell the TTS say something and the form closed itself, viewing again the 1st form. Ok.

The problem starts when I click two times in the button on the 2nd form: the TTS says something, the button closes and the 'second click' is still in the click buffer (or somewhere) and it makes click in the 1st form (which appears 4 seconds later when I hit the button for the first time).
I am using the voice in a Sync mode; if I use the voice in an Async mode, the application ends wit h a nice exception.
If I click three or four times in the 2nd form, the other clicks still remains in buffer and clicks in the 1st form all the times.

I tried to (1) delete the DoubleClick event, (2) delete the event associated to the button and (3) hide the button which is clicked automatically when I return from the 2nd form, (4) hide the 1st form before create the 2nd and restore when it finishes.

Suggestions?
Thanks!

PD: I'm sorry by my English :S

PD2: [I've uploaded a very simple example](http://www.mediafire.com/?a6yjnida0antt7f) of what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

Having looked at the code I understand the issue you're having now.  The reason button clicks are being stacked up is when you call Speak within TTS the application locks up while it waits for the function to finish.  Any presses in that time are stacked up until the application is free again to process them, you then close the form instanly before the messages are handled and these are then dealt with in the first form.

I've come up with a few solutions which could work for you:

1. Use only the SpeakAsync command within your TTS class and introduce a Waiting system where you wait for the speech to finish before doing anything.  This will free the application and won't cause the mouse click events to stack up.
2. After you trigger a Speak command you could access the Windows message list and clear all the mouse click events that occurred before the process finished.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how you'd implement this as I've not done this before.  I think you need to overwrite the WndProc function but again I'm not sure. This might be also be a bit dangerous as you may end up clearing a perfectly valid or important system message by mistake.  Sorry can't provide any more help on that one.
3. Implement a background worker in your second form which will process the Speak commands seperately on a background thread.  This again will free the application so the mouse click events won't stack up.  I've modified your sample project and zipped it up for you to take a look.  If you want I can explain further but essentially it does the following:

   - Form 2 loads and creates a background worker.
   - Worker_DoWork and Worker_WorkComplete delegates are created and set in the background worker.  These functions are called when the worker is started and after the worker has finished.
   - Form 2 triggers the background worker to start.  The background worker then sits in an infinite loop waiting for commands to process.
   - When the "Hello" button is pressed this sets a SayHello boolean to true, the worker spots this, carrys out the appropriate speak function and then resets the boolean ready for the next press.
   - When the "Close" button is pressed a CancelASync request is called in the background worker.
   - CancelASync interupts the BackgroundWorker's main loop (CancellationPending becomes true).  The appropriate speak command is sent and the cancel property of the DoWorkEventArgs is set to true before breaking out of the BackgroundWorker's main loop.
   - Breaking out of the main loop causes Worker_WorkComplete to be called where the form is then closed.

I hope you can follow the example (linked below) and I've explained it well enough here.  I prefer this solution as its quite extendable, you can add more conditions within the main worker thread for example.

Like I said, if you have any questions please ask and I'll try help as much as possible.

Hope this helps.

Example Link: http://www.mediafire.com/?2mf1yahto50ljs6

Comment: Did not work.
It is not only that button, the clicks remain in the buffer and could click anywhere in the 2nd form.
If hiding the 1st form doesn't work, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Oh I see apologies I misread the question.  I'll edit my answer now and see if the new solution helps you.

Comment: I've made the Edits @zaba I hope I've got the jist of your problem now and given you a viable solution.  Let me know if you get any more difficulties

Comment: I can't acces to the e.Handled method in the event. It is correctly write?

Comment: Added a link with a mini-example-project.

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake I got confused with EventArgs, MouseEventArgs doesn't have a handled property.  I've downloaded the project and I'll get back to you as soon as I can with any help

Comment: @zaba I've provided an example along with an edit of my original answer.  It seems the issue you're having is the application locks up while you wait for Speak to complete, this inturn stacks up any mouse clicks that occur.  The example I wrote seems to work fine for me, I don't have any speakers/headfones here in work unfortunately so couldn't test fully but seemed to debug ok :) let me know how you get on.

Comment: Yes, it works!! Finally. Now I have to integrate your code to mine, a several times :/ I have to use the third option because the TTS will speak in several languages, and timing changes.
Thank you very, very much!!

Comment: @zaba Just glad I could help, fingers crossed you can limit the amount of times you have to repeat the code :)  Just a word of warning though so you're aware...It seems modifying a form control in the BackgroundWorker's do work function will cause the BackgroundWorker to complete and in turn call its WorkComplete function...I noticed it happening when trying to Enable a button in Worker_DoWork...But other than that, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean flag to track whether the form is in a state that accepts the click.

IE - when you open the 2nd form, 'boolean canPlaySound = true;'  When the button click event fires, only play the sound if canPlaySound is true (and set it to false before playing the sound).

The next click will be ignored because canPlaySound = false.  You won't play the sound.